# Validity of "TV was not always the place to find contemporary comics any more."

Tags: grammaticality

From [an article by *The Guardian*:](https://www.theguardian.com/culture/2023/aug/20/how-impressionists-keep-audiences-laughing-in-an-age-of-social-media-celebrities)

> Platforms such as TikTok and Instagram, Kempner added, offered huge opportunities to do more niche impressions. “People are coming to that video wanting impressions of their favourite show. Love Island? Line Of Duty? Succession?”
>
> Culshaw echoed this, **saying TV was not always the place to find contemporary comics any more.** “A lot of younger impressionists these days come through YouTube. In the past we’d record tapes and post them to a producer, now you do your own thing in your bedroom or garage and hope it goes viral,” he said.

If TV was not always a place to find contemporary comics, then what is the sense of using 'any more' abruptly?
How can 'not always' and 'any more' be used together?

Comment: You're missing that it's a quote. He probably said "TV **is** not always the place to find contemporary comics any more." In quoting, the verb *was* reflects that he said that in the past. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of **reported speech** ([British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/reported-speech-statements)) - Culshaw's actual words were "TV **is** not always the place to find contemporary comics any more", which is grammatically OK.  The writer of the article has followed the standard convention of putting the reported speech into the simple past (changing "is" to "was"), which makes the sentence rather uncomfortable, as you note.  A better sentence would be:

> Culshaw echoed this, saying [that] TV is not always the place to find contemporary comics any more.

See the British Council page under "No backshift" for other examples.

Comment: Can you please clarify this:
If the statement said 'TV is not always the place to find contemporary comics'. What is the difference created when 'any more' is used?

Comment: @codeactor The use of "any more" tells us that TV was _once_ the place to find contemporary comics.  Without it, the statement could mean "TV was _never_ the place to find contemporary comics".  (Incidentally, I assume that "comics" here means "comedians" rather than "comic strips").